# Can ocsigen be run in toplevel?

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

I used to run YAWS in erlang's REPL by just running `yaws -i`.  When yaws is running, I can continue to use erlang's REPL.

Then I want to know whether or not it is possible to run ocsigen in OCaml's toplevel? Of course, it is not a practical use of ocsigen, but as an exercise.

I have tried thread as below, but it did not work:

```
λ> #thread;;
λ> Thread.create (fun _ -> Sys.command "ocsigen -c ~/ocsigen.conf.qachina") ();;
-: Thread.t = <abstr>
```

it works great!
BTW, What does the "abstr" stands for ?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: abstr means that the return value ( of type Thread.t ) have no registered printer in the toplevel. If you want to print some information about threads, you could register one using the #install_printer directive. ( see http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual023.html#toc90 for more informations )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable threads in toplevel with `#thread`.

Though I am not sure what this question has to do with ocsigen.